# Meaning of $|z|=i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was thinking about solutions of equation $x^2=i$ . First thought coming to my mind was $x=\pm \sqrt{i}$ . ( I know it's wrong ) .
Then I thought if we solve this equation like real problem then
$|x|=\sqrt i$ ( Again wrong ) .

But it got me thinking that we define |z| as distance of complex number z from origin . But what if this distance is not real so let consider complex numbers z whose $|z|=i$ .

> Does this question make sense ? Does such numbers exist on complex x - y plane ? Do we need to include another dimensions for such numbers ?

Sorry if this question seems silly and thanks for help !

Comment: ”But what if this distance is not real...“ No, the distance, by definition, **is** real. For *any* complex number $z=a+bi$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, a nonnegative *real* number.

Comment: Notice that $(1+i)^2 = 2i$.  You might plot $1+i$ and $2i$ in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if this distance is not real so let consider complex numbers $z$ whose $|z|=i$.

No, the "distance (from a complex number to another)" is a nonnegative real number by definition. It does not make sense to write $|z|=i$.

> I was thinking about solutions of equation $x^2=i$.

There are two solutions to the complex equation $z^2=i$. (One usually uses $z$ as the unknown variable for complex equations.)

One way to solve this equation is using the polar form of complex numbers. Write $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $i=e^{i\pi/2}$. Then
$$
r^2e^{i2\theta} = e^{i\pi/2+2k\pi},\quad (r\ge 0)
$$
It follows that $r=1$ and $\theta=\pi/4+k\pi$. Thus the two solutions are
$$
z_1=e^{i\pi/4},\quad z_2=e^{i5\pi/4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{i}$ can be defined, simply take and $8$-th root of unity. You can also compute it explicitely in the following way, by Euler's formula $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ so a square root of $i$ is given by $\pm e^{i\pi/4}=\pm(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$. You can check directly that these are the correct values.

Distance in the complex numbers is defined as a real number. I do not know of any generalisation of the distance where complex numbers are allowed, however I expect that such a thing would not match your intuition of distance.

Comment: You shouls say first that $|z|=i$ has no solution !

Comment: @JeanMarie well of course it doesn't, I said the distance (norm) is a real number.

Answer (score 0):

As squid correctly pointed out in the comments, the distance is by definition **real**. We induce and construct norms over spaces that help us measure distance for this exact reason, regardless their elements.

As of such, the expression $|z| = i$ doesn't stand.

The standard norm over $\mathbb C$ that help us measure distance, is:
$$z = a + ib: \quad a,b \in R$$

$$|\cdot|_\mathbb C : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R \quad \text{such that} \quad |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$$

Finally, as you correctly stated, the expression $|z|$ means the distance of the complex number $z \in \mathbb C$ from the complex origin.